# How do i find the ip adress of a user of my website and email it to me?

Tags: javascript, html, email

I want my website to email the IP addresses of the visitors to me. I can't find anything online about how to do it.

Comment: Both are different tasks. _1._ Getting IP address of the user _2._ Sending email. Search them individually and you will get the answer.

Comment: You can not send email with java script  you need server side language to do it

Comment: If you want a report of visitors to your website, maybe try https://www.google.com/analytics?

Comment: Have a look at complete systems: http://www.awstats.org/ or google analytics or something of that sort. If you are implementing it yourself, you do need a server-side (PHP or so) script to do this job... but how often do you need that? per-day? per-visit?

Comment: maybe you can find something helpful here http://goo.gl/5ghbMi

Answer (score 0):

This are two different tasks that can be done in the back-end of your system. How to do it depends entirely on your current environment. For example, if you are using a framework like [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) all you need to do is to set up your ***settings.py*** file with your current mail address and maybe with the **logs system** track every request done to your site and send an email to you automatically containing all the info you want about the visitors, not only their IP address. I said maybe because there are other ways to achieve the same task.